# CakePHP Manipulate more than one models in the same controller

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, model, controller

1. I created two plugins in the CakePHP, and both of them have the same named model, e.g, plugin1.mod and plugin2.mod.
2. In the two models, defined the same named method, e.g, mymethod.
3. Now, I have a controller in my main program. Then, use ClassRegistry::init to initialize plugin1 and can call plugin1.mod without problem.

Problem：

When I use `ClassRegistry::init` to initialize plugin2 and call the plugin2.mod, it is calling plugin1.mod! Can somebody tell me what wrong here is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 2.0 this is not possible (anymore).
class paths are cached (inside App class) and therefore can use a class name only once.

You need to use different class names.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
In fact, I have not only 2 plugins in my project. And I designed the project more commonly as several plugins have the same model(class) names.

Comment: For the record: I dont like it either :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

In fact, I have not only 2 plugins in my project. 
Because I designed the project more commonly as several plugins have the same model(class) names.

In your opinion, I have to use different name for each model(class)?
I do indeed try to change the model(class) name to another one temporarily and it works. 
But have I to change every model(class) name to the different one? It's so pity...:(

By the way, I am still using CakePHP 1.3. :)